# How to immediately close ethclient.Client RPC sockets so they don't linger in TIME_WAIT status on server?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, concurrency

My server is running out of available sockets while I am using goroutines (limited to 100 concurrently) because once a goroutine finishes the ethclient.Client socket stays open in TIME_WAIT status for too long, instead of closing immediately after it has returned the required data, as is mentioned in [this issue comment](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1549#issuecomment-127087352).

After about 30000 sockets are sitting in TIME_WAIT then my app fails. Sockets are closed faster on macOS 10.13 than on Ubuntu 14.04 it seems, as the problem is less common on a Mac.

The golang net package allows you to set SO_LINGER to 0 via [setLinger](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetLinger) but I don't see a similar option for ethclient.Client but maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

it's not an Ethereum question, but you can find the clue here:

```
[root@ethnode /root]# echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

Comment: it's inside a docker container on GKE so I can't edit those system level values, I'd much prefer to shutdown the connection on the client side than trying to manage it on each server